# How to do running sum for inventory purposes in Excel?

Tags: excel, sum, inventory

I have a problem I can't figure out for the life of me. It seems very straight forward but...

[image: Problem in question]

I have two columns as you see **Qty ordered** and **On Stock**. I would like to add a third column titled **Remaining stock**.

On the **Stock** column is the current status of inventory and it's repeated for all apples from our software. In the third column, I would like to be able to see how it's consumed and when it goes out. I tried `SUMIFS` and `VLOOKUPs` but that's all my knowledge of Excel functions.

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SUMIF` function should work:

```
=C2-SUMIF($A$2:A2,A2,$B$2:B2)
```

[image]

Comment: This my man worked like a charm. I don't understand how it works but it works. Many thankyous!